# gdb with with the .C interface (shared object)

Tags: c, r, debugging, interface, gdb

I am calling a shared object coded in `C` from a `R` wrapper via the [.C](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/interface.pdf). The `C` code cause segmentation faults and I would like to use [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to help me debug this code.

Is it possible to use `gdb` with the .C interface?

I am on MAC OSX 10.11.3

Comment: I don't see why not. Did you try starting R in debug mode (`R --debugger=gdb`)?

Comment: I am a bit confused as I am used to follow the `gdb` command by an executable. When I do `R --debugger=gdb`, R opens (there is no `(dgb)` prompt). I can then source() my R.wrapper and it executes but I don't seem to have the gdb interface. Just like before, we reach the segmentation fault in the middle of the `C` code and I receive a message from `R` informing me of the segmentation fault. It just looked like it was before. Can you help me out?

Comment: You definitely have `gdb` installed right? Also, which operating system are you on? `gdb` should have started right up with the command above; I will add a more detailed example below in a minute to demonstrate.

Comment: Yes, `gdb` is installed and it works fine on executable. I am on MAC OS X 10.11.3 (info added to post). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you try passing the full path to `gdb`, e.g. `R -d /path/to/gdb`, instead of just `R -d gdb`?

Comment: Oh this seems to work! .... I got it I had some trouble with my gdb actually... was not correctly installed actually (despite what I said above!). Fixed now, it works with `R -d gdb` as well. You can probably amek an answer out of your comment if you want

Comment: I actually still have trouble but I realize my question is not specific about the .C interface but about the use of `gdb` with R. I guess I will just let you post your answer and will open a new post that explain more accurately what kind of error message I get with `R -d gdb`. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you are calling compiled code via `.C` or `.Call` should not matter WRT to debugging an R session via `gdb`. As an example, consider the code below which **intentionally causes a segfault** (on my system) by dereferencing a null pointer:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void rtest(void)
{
    int* p = NULL;
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}
```

Compile this with `R CMD SHLIB rtest.c`, and start R using either of

- `R -d /path/to/gdb`
- `R --debugger=/path/to/gdb`

Or, if `gdb` is on your `PATH`, you don't need the full file path above. At any rate, start the R session:

```
nathan@nathan-deb:/tmp$ R --debugger=gdb

#GNU gdb (Debian 7.7.1+dfsg-5) 7.7.1
#Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
#
# omitted
#
#Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/R/bin/exec/R...done.
#
(gdb) r
```

Then load the shared library, call the function, and proceed with your debugging session:

```
dyn.load("rtest.so")
f <- function() .C("rtest")
f()

#Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#rtest () at rtest.c:8
#8      printf("%d\n", *p);
```